# When trying to read a file in C++ my file gets appended a weird character sequence

Tags: c++, text, character, fstream

I'm having really weird problem with a program I'm building in c++, what's important here is that the constructor for this object ("Scanner") recieves a vector with some file names, now what I want to do is pass all of these onto another file and from there pass it all onto a stringstream for decoding elsewhere, it was all working perfectly until I tried to do it with two files where suddenly the last one gets the characters sequence "\200\001" appended to it for some strange reason and that screws up my whole program, now the weird thing is it only happens on some files and not on others and I'm frankly stumped as to what is happening.

Here's the relevant code:

```
Scanner::Scanner(vector<string> files):
lineCount(1),
colCount(-1),
needToken(true),
lastToken(0),
lbl(false)
{
  ifstream ifile;
  ofstream ofile("temp.calc", ofstream::trunc);
  ofile.close();
  for(vector<string>::iterator it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); ++it){
    ofile.open("temp.calc", ofstream::binary | ofstream::app);
    ifile.open((*it).c_str(), ifstream::binary);
    if(ifile.is_open() && ofile.is_open()){
      ifile.seekg(0,ifile.end);
      long size = ifile.tellg();
      ifile.seekg(0);
      char * buffer = new char[size];
      ifile.read(buffer,size);
      ofile.write(buffer,size);
      delete[] buffer;
      ifile.close();
      ofile.close();
    }
  }
  ifile.open("temp.calc");
  ifile.seekg(0,ifile.end);
  long size = ifile.tellg();
  ifile.seekg(0);
  char * buffer = new char[size];
  ifile.read(buffer,size);
  inStream = new istringstream(buffer);
  ifile.close();
  delete[] buffer;
}
```

I'm truly and absolutely bewildered as to why it happens, and it doesn't always, for examples I might use expresion1.calc and expresion2.calc and it works file, or I might use expresion3.calc or 4 by themselves and it works, but if I combine those two in particular everything gets screwed up.

here are what the files that cause the problem contain:
expresion3.calc

```
a = 3 + 4;\n
```

expresion4.calc

```
b = 3 * 4;\n
```

That's all that's inside them and yet, when I check the contents of buffer with gdb, after the \n there will be \200\001.

I could really use the help guys, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::istringstream` takes a `std::string` as input.  You are passing it a `char*` instead.  So a temporary `std::string` is created, and it expects the `char*` to be null terminated, which your code is not enforcing.  I would suggest you explicitly create a `std::string` so you can pass the buffer `size` to its constructor:

```
inStream = new istringstream(string(buffer, size));
```

On a side note, you are closing, re-opening, and re-seeking the output file on each loop iteration. You do not need to do that, that is wasted overhead.  Leave the file open the whole time the loop is running, then close it when finished:

```
  ofstream ofile("temp.calc", ofstream::binary | ofstream::trunc);
  if (ofile.is_open()){
    for(vector<string>::iterator it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); ++it){
      ifile.open((*it).c_str(), ifstream::binary);
      if(ifile.is_open()){
        ...
        ofile.write(buffer,size);
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  ofile.close();
```

Comment: That did it, thank you so much! I had no idea it was ideal to creat e a std::string, I genuinely thought a char* could work, thanks!